# CakePHP 2.x Auth Condition

Tags: cakephp, authentication, conditional-statements

In my User Authentication I need to set a Condition (verified = 1) for the Login to happen. I know that I should be able to do it like this:

```
$this->Auth->userScope = array('User.verified' => '1');
```

I tried this in AppController and my UsersController beforeFilter function, but it doesn't do anything. Is there anything else I need to configure for this?

I ended up doing (AppController):

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {

if ($user['verified'] == '0') { 
$this->Session->setFlash('You need to verify your Account first.');
return false;
}

return false;
}
```

This seems to be inelegant, since there should be the proper (userScope) way to do it, plus I now get two Flashes when verified = 0: The first one is the setFlash from above, and the second one is the regular authError.

I checked both, the Docs and stackoverflow, but I found very little information on this topic.

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376343/cakephp-2-x-auth-condition

Comment: @nIcO, seems it is duplicating itself :)

Comment: @kode Wohoo ! Nice ! I guess I pasted the wrong url... ;-)

Answer (score 10):

CakePHP 2.x:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller'    => 'users',
            'action'        => 'login'
        ),
        'authError' => 'Je hebt geen toegang tot dit gedeelte',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                'scope' => array('is_admin' => '1')
            ),

        )
    ),
    'Session'
);
```

Update: For cakePHP 3.1 finder `option` is available since 3.1. Prior to that you can use `scope` and `contain` options to modify query.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query

Comment: the scope needs to be inside the 'auth'=>'authenticate'=>'Form' array. That was the solution that worked for me. To answer your question:no.

Comment: Ah, alright, I was confused because the question says `verified` but your answer reads `is_admin`.

Comment: +1 - This seems like the correct solution for applications that only have form-based authentication (most cases). If you happen to have multiple authentication handlers (form/basic/digest/custom) then @tigrang's solution will let you apply the scope to all handlers.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    AuthComponent::ALL => array(
        'scope' => array('User.verified' => '1'),
   ),
);
```

Comment: what type of field is verified? Try either `true` or `1`

Comment: Tried true and 1, but to no change. The field that is verified is tinyint(1)

Comment: the sql dump is empty … but so it is for the if clause in the isAuthorized function. Am i looking at this in a wrong way?

Comment: if it locks every user out, then the users dont have verified value set to 1 in the table. Also isAuthorized() is only called for logged in users(so the login actually worked), so make sure isAuthorized retrurns true as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
      'Form' => array(
                'scope' => array('User.verified' => '1')
      )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the CakePHP Documentation is correct `Auth::userScope` was renamed to `Auth::scope` so now you would do something like this:

```
$this->Auth->scope = array ('User.active' => '1');
```

[Configuring Auth in CakePHP 2.x](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)

Hope this helps.

Comment: tigrang's answer should work. CakePHP's documentation is crappy as always, only in the API reference can you find this little gem: http://api.cakephp.org/class/auth-component

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$this->Auth->userScope = array('User.verified = 1');`

Comment: This line resembles exactly a working app I have (only changing the field name). I'm pretty sure this format works so you problem might be on another config.

Comment: Are you on 2.x? Do you have any Idea what config could be wrong?